# Creating a discriminated union using the property names of another type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a generic type that takes the property names and property types from a type and use them to make a discriminated union type. For example:

```
type FooBar = {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
};
```

would map to:

```
type FooBarPair = {
    key: "foo",
    value: string
} | {
    key: "bar",
    value: number
}
```

My initial attempt is:

```
type Pairs<T> = {
    [TKey in keyof T]: {
        key: TKey;
        value: T[TKey];
    };
};

type Pair<T> = Pairs<T>[keyof T];
```

but when I try to apply this to the type above:

```
let pair: Pair<FooBar> = {
    key: "foo",
    value: 3
};
```

I would expect a compile error but there isn't one. When I inspect the type of `Pair<FooBar>` I find it equates to:

```
{
    key: "foo" | "bar";
    value: string | number;
}
```

I think this might be a bug in typescript but I wanted to see if there was some other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way to achieve this. It turns out that Typescript infers the desired type

```
 `{ key: "foo"; value: string; } | { key: "bar"; value: number; }`
```

when you remove intermediate generic type `type Pair<T> = Pairs<T>[keyof T];` and expand it inline like `Pairs<FooBar>[keyof FooBar]` every time you would have used it:

```
type Pairs<T> = {
    [TKey in keyof T]: {
        key: TKey;
        value: T[TKey];
    };
};

type FooBar = {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
};


let pair: Pairs<FooBar>[keyof FooBar] = {
    key: "foo",
    value: 3
};
```

the complete error message is

```
Type '{ key: "foo"; value: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ key: "foo"; value: string; } | { key: "bar"; value: number; }'.
  Type '{ key: "foo"; value: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ key: "foo"; value: string; }'.
    Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I'm not sure what's the "correct" type to infer in either case, but introduction of shorthand type like `Pair<T> = Pairs<T>[keyof T]` should not affect type inference IMO. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I agree seems like a bug, I'll raise an issue with typescript.