# Reason for [typof T] in generics having different semantics that a hard coded type?

Tags: typescript, algebraic-data-types, typescript-generics

So there is a trick I found in typescript to turn an object type into a discriminated union by mapping the type to key-value pair then creating a type that can be any value in the map using the `keyof` type. Here is a simple example:

```
type SourceType =
{
    foo: number,
    bar: string
};
type MapWithKey<T> = {[P in keyof T]: { key: P, value: T[P] }}
type DescriminatedUnion = MapWithKey<SourceType>[keyof SourceType];
//The DescriminatedUnion now has the following type
DescriminatedUnion ≡ {key:"foo",value:string} | {key:"bar",value:number}
```

This is very useful if you want to specify a very large discriminated union however when you try to make this construct fully generic you end up with a different type.

```
type MakeDescriminatedUnion<T> = MapWithKey<T>[keyof T];
type DescriminatedUnion = MakeDescriminatedUnion<SourceType>
//The DescriminatedUnion now has the followin type
DescriminatedUnion ≡ {key:"foo"|"bar",value:number|string}
```

This should be the same type but for some reason it isn't. I have tried to look through the typescript documentation to find some reasoning for this behavior however I cannot. Does anyone know the reasoning behind this difference? Or even better does anyone know a way to get around this behavior and make it fully generic?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898999/creating-a-discriminated-union-using-the-property-names-of-another-type) looks very similar, here is [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15756), and [here is the fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18042)

Comment: Thanks! That is way more than I expected. @artem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15756) has bitten [me](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17908) and [quite](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16018) a few [others](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17930).  It's amazing that, as @artem mentions, [a fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18042) slated for TypeScript 2.6 was introduced just today!

Meanwhile, for those of us stuck in TypeScript 2.4-land, there is a workaround using [default generic type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2175):

```
type MakeDiscriminatedUnion<T, M extends MapWithKey<T> = MapWithKey<T>> = M[keyof T];
type DiscriminatedUnion = MakeDiscriminatedUnion<SourceType> // okay now
```

The actual value of `M` doesn't get evaluated until you use `MakeDiscriminatedUnion<SourceType>`, so the compiler has no chance to "simplify" `M[keyof T]` the way it does above.

Anyway, it's your choice whether to use the workaround or wait for TypeScript 2.6.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the work around! Couldn't find it anywhere else works flawlessly!